# How do i select columns from table 2 inside row of table 1

Tags: mysql, node.js

How do i select from table 2 and show inside table 1,sql correct statement ?

Example:

```
Table 1 row
A B C D

Table 2 columns
 x 
 y 
 z
```

How do i

```
SELECT * FROM Users
```

as single row [[A] [B] [C] [D] [x y z]]  ?

if i do SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE id = "k", i get 1 result

if i do SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE id = "k",i get 3 results

i want all 3 results from table 2 to show in table1 in result 1

Another example : 
SELECT * FROM table1 LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.id WHERE table1.id = '" + k + "'"

i get this : [[result1 table 1],[result1 table2]],[result1 table 1],[result2 table2]]] incorrect for me

i want [[result1 table 1],[result1 table2]],[result2 table2]]]

subquery NOT as solution as it limits me to 1 row

Comment: You can probably JOIN the 2 tables.

Comment: i tried that it gives me [ [ [ x ] [A] [B] [C] [D] ],[ [ y ] [A] [B] [C] [D] ],[ [ z ] [A] [B] [C] [D] ]] , i want   [[A] [B] [C] [D] [x y z d.....n]]

Comment: See if you can provide a better example. And see: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT * 
  FROM `table_1` 
  LEFT 
  JOIN `table_2` 
    ON `table_1`.id=`table_2`.id_table1 
 WHERE id_table1
```

Obviously the id_table1 has to be the id that matches both tables in a relation of 1:N

I hope you find this usefull.

Comment: nope gives result as i said ... if i do SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE id = "k" i get 1 result ,if i do SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE id = "k",i get 3 results  ,i want  all 3 results from table 2 to show in table1 in result 1